# Not able to Identify Special Character in .txt File

Tags: c#, .net, special-characters

I have .txt file which was generated by my application , which we send to Bank every day as part of Payment Processing , but recently Bank observed that in Non prod environment we are sending special Character in 1st row and 1st column itself (file contains three characters in the beginning of the file) , like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lud7g.png)
**Newley added Rows**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB2g6.png)

But when we open the file and verify we don't see any as such special character in the file, so could you please suggest me, do we have any tool to check the special character in the .txt file ?
your help will be much appreciated

I am in windows OS

Comment: Ask them to send you the file, and compare it to the file you _think_ you sent them.

Comment: Sounds like a BOM. Open it with Notepad++ and it should tell you what type. You could also use hex editor like HxD or write some code to dump out the bytes. I'd guess utf-8, it's the only common one that is 3 bytes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you mjwills - Yes they are also not able to see the special character when they open the File, but their File Parser software is detecting that their is a special character in our file

Comment: Almost certainly a BOM then.

Comment: So are you suggesting me to go for Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes() ? Currently I have Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()  in my code

Comment: Even in NotePad ++ there is no clue - I am not able to see the special character

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+see+BOM+in+file

Comment: @Manas Notepad++ doesn't show you the characters, but in the lower right it will show the encoding, like UTF-8-BOM. You can also see the encoding in the Encoding menu.

Comment: mjwills  - I followed the same steps which is mentioned here https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-remove-bom-any-textxml-file , Still I don't see the special characters (o;?) in my file

Comment: Retired Ninja - I can see that  in my NotePad ++   in the lower right corner, it is - UTF-8-BOM , but question how I can see the special characters (o;?) in the file

Comment: To see the leading bytes, use a Hex viewer/editor, or use `File.ReadAllBytes()` and inspect the first 3 bytes. But you can just save the file as UTF-8 NO-BOM. This *version* can be saved using standard .Net methods (e.g., `File.WriteAllText([Path], [Content])` or `new StreamWriter([Path]` etc.) .

Comment: It's kind of weird that a procedure that imports UTF-8 encoded files cannot handle the BOM, though.

Comment: Jimi - Thanks for the response -  I have opened the File in NotePad ++ and then in Encoding Menu I have changed to UTF-8 instead of UTF-8 BOM, But I still not able to see the special Characters and even I have saved the file

Comment: UTF-8 without BOM doesn't have any *special bytes* anymore, so you cannot *see* anything after you change format. As mentioned, you need a hex/byte viewer (or an advanced editor as UltraEdit ,which lets you switch text/structure/Hex view on the fly). Normal editors don't show the BOM (those bytes are not something you're supposed to *edit*).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this could be because of a mismatch in [text encoding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/choose-text-encoding-when-you-open-and-save-files-60d59c21-88b5-4006-831c-d536d42fd861) that you are using when you create the file vs. what is being expected by the receiver of this file.

Comment: Hi SwaroSh, Thanks for your response, Basically its an existing  .txt file and application since 10 years. We only added new row to that .txt File and now Bank Processer (3rd Party)  its saying we are sending special character at the beginning of the File, But we are sure we are not sending, so How do I verify from my end in the .txt file that I have special character ?

Comment: `We only added new row to that .txt File` Show us the file. Particularly that first row.

Comment: When you added the new row, are you using one of .NET's built-in encoding functions (e.g. shown below)?  Instead, if the data that you are writing is from a source whose encoding is unknown, it could lead to the issue you are describing.

    `var file = File.Create("test.txt");`
    `var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello world");`
    `file.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

Comment: I have added new image which has - newly added rows information

Comment: Newly added rows used the same way how it was handled earlier - Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()